# How is the order of statements gives a different answer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-theory

arent both statements equivalent? so both should be false?

[image]

Comment: In general, the order of a "for all" and a "there exists" is very important, and affects the meaning of the statement. If $\exists$ comes first, in something like $\exists x\text{ s.t. } \forall y \ldots$, the *same $x$* must work simultaneously for *all $y$* (so $x$ cannot depend on $y$). However, if the $\forall$ comes first, in something like $\forall y\, \exists x\text{ s.t. }\ldots$, the $x$ is *allowed to depend on $y$*, i.e. we are allowed to have different $x$ for different $y$. Thus your two statements are **not** equivalent.

Comment: " If ∃ comes first, in something like ∃ s.t. ∀…, the same  must work simultaneously for all  (so  cannot depend on )." then shouldnt it be written as     !∃ meaning a unique x

Comment: When writing $\exists x\forall y$ we say nothing about how many $x$ are such that they work for all $y$ simultaneously; there is at least one, but may just as well be many. With $\exists!x\forall y$, there is exactly one $x$ that works for all $y$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Both statements are not equivalent. In the first one, it says there is an $x$ ( a real number) for each and every real number $y$ such that $xy=1$. This is clearly untrue. For example, for $y=5$, the only $x$ that will yield $xy=1$ will be $\frac15$. But this $x=\frac15$ is not the multiplicative inverse of any other real number.

In the second statement, it says for every $y$ there exists an $x$ such that $xy=1$. This is different in that it says that the $x$ for each $y$ does not have to be the same real number as opposed to what was implied by the first statement. And, of course, this is true. Because, for any $y=z$, the multiplicative inverse would be $\frac1z$.

Comment: Also, the second statement is only true if we are talking about all real numbers excluding 0. 0 does not have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: true, $\mathbb{R}^\ast$ is the set of non-zero reals.

Comment: Thank you! I was not familiar with the terminology

Comment: For any unary ring $R$, $R^\ast$ is the set of multiplicative units. This is a commonly used special case.

Comment: for the first statement, it doesnt say a unique solution !E, so i can change the X for every Y making it true? right

Comment: You cannot change the x in statement 1. Why? Because it says that there exists an x for every Y (which means they are saying that I can have one real number x such that whenever I multiply that number with any of the numbers in R*, the answer will be identity). It talks about the existence of one such x which applies to all Y.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you showed is correct

$$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^\ast: \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^\ast: xy=1\tag{i}$$

is false; there is no $x$ that works for all $y$, but

$$\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^\ast: \exists x \in \mathbb{R}^\ast: xy=1\tag{ii}$$

is true, as for every $y$ we can find an $x$.

This is how the semantics of these statements is defined. Read up on it..
There are hidden brackets here, really:

$$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^\ast: \left(\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^\ast: xy=1\right)\tag{i'}$$

e.g. and the $x$ is a "constant" (bound variable) within the bracketed statement. So the statement holds if we can find an $x$ such that for that specific $x$ the inner statement holds, and for that, for each $y$ the statement $xy=1$ should hold, which it does not. Etc.